# POST a WebForm with encrypted viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I am working on an application to automate some task we do a lot here. I am using the `WebClient` class, which I have overridden in order  to support cookies.

The first step is to logon to the application in our test environment. The web application is in a load balanced farm with two servers and uses ViewState encryption. I looked at the POST made by `Chrome` in `Fiddler` and replicated the POST exactly. Each header and element in the form is found in my `WebClient` request. The POST is a partial postback (using an update panel).

The problem is that I get an `Invalid viewstate` error in the returned response. I am using this code to extract the viewstate `value` from the hidden tag in the initial GET request:

```
        var viewStateNameDelimiter = "__VIEWSTATE";
        var valueDelimiter = "value=\"";

        var viewStateNamePosition = html.IndexOf(viewStateNameDelimiter);
        var viewStateValuePosition = html.IndexOf(
              valueDelimiter, viewStateNamePosition
           );

        var viewStateStartPosition = viewStateValuePosition +
                                     valueDelimiter.Length;
        var viewStateEndPosition = html.IndexOf("\"", viewStateStartPosition);

        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                 html.Substring(
                    viewStateStartPosition,
                    viewStateEndPosition - viewStateStartPosition
                 )
              );
```

And I add it to the request with this code:

```
var data = new NameValueCollection();
var viewState = extractor.ExtractViewState(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(getResponse));
data.Add("__VIEWSTATE", viewState);
```

When I look at the request made by this console application, and compare it to the Chrome request, everything seems the same (admittedly, I did not verify each of the 2K+ chars there :)). I don't get why this isn't working. I am mimicing the browser request as perfectly as I can see.

Comment: Are you sending the reconstructed request from the same computer from which you are sending the browser request?

Comment: In the reconstructed request, are you posting the viewstate to the same URL as the URL from which the ViewState was created?

Comment: @user469104 - Also, Yes. I tried doing this both on the server and on my local machine and got the same error.

Comment: Paste both viewstate values into a hash generator, like this one (http://www.sha1-online.com/), or just generate a hash through .NET and verify if they are the same. Knowing if they are the same or not would be an important data point.

Comment: @user469104 - Hmm... Good idea. Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @user469104 - Both the `VIEWSTATE` and `EVENTVALIDATION` tag contents received in the GET and sent on POST generate the same hash.